# What is the best way to evaluate two variables representing a single pipeline command in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, bioinformatics, pipeline

I have a function `produce` which determines whether a file is present and if not it runs the following command. This works fine when the command output simply writes to stdout. However in the command below I pipe the output to a second command and then to a third command before it outputs to stdout. In this scenario I get the output writing to file correctly but it does not echo the preceding $@ from the produce function and the contents of the initial unpopulated outputfile.vcf (contains header columns) which is generated by the pipeline command on execution is also being outputted to stdout. Is there a more appropriate way to evaluate `$@ > "${curfile}"`

```
   produce() {
    local curfile=$1
    #Remove the first element of the list of passed arguments
    shift
    if [ ! -e "${curfile}" ]; then
    #Run the subsequent command as shown in the list of passed arguments
       echo $@
       $@ > "${curfile}"
    fi
    }


   produce outputfile.vcf samtools view -bq 20 input.bam | samtools mpileup -Egu -t DP,SP -f hs37d5formatted.fa -| bcftools call -cNv -
```

Comment: I can't believe that "it does not echo the preceding $@". What happens when you remove all of the trailing pipeline, don't you see the output? if no then something is really weird. Can you `"echo important commands" | samtools mpileup ...` (without using a function) and get it to work? My guess is that samtools needs a special arg to know it should read from stdin. Good luck.

Comment: Yes shellter it doesn't make sense why it does not echo the preceding $@. If I remove the trailing pipeline and just write to file the output of the first command then it works as expected. And yes I can `"echo important commands" | samtools mpileup ... ` (without using a function). I think perhaps there is an issue relating to how the arguments are fed to the function produce. I think the perhaps there is some issue with how the pipe character maybe is being translated from $@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok as I mentioned in my comment the issue seems to relate to the pipe characters so I had to evaluate the variable using `eval` and escape the pipe character. So in order to ensure the function `produce` interprets `$@` correctly I fed the command as follows. Note also that the variables are all now quoted

```
 #######

 produce() {
local curfile="$1"
#Remove the first element of the list of passed arguments
shift
if [ ! -e "${curfile}" ]; then
#Run the subsequent command as shown in the list of passed arguments
   echo "$@"
   eval "$@ > ${curfile}"
fi
}


produce outputfile.vcf samtools view -bq 20 input.bam \| samtools mpileup -Egu -t DP,SP -f hs37d5formatted.fa -\| bcftools call -cNv -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>>` to append to a file. For example:

```
echo "line 1" >> filename
echo "line 2" >> filename
```

Will result in a file containing:

```
line 1
line 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply HenryTK but the issue persists if I use append.